# Python List indexed by tuples

Tags: python, list, matlab, list-comprehension

I'm a Matlab user needing to use Python for some things, I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out with Python syntax:

(1) Is it true that lists can be indexed by tuples in Python?  If so, how do I do this?  For example, I would like to use that to represent a matrix of data.

(2) Assuming I can use a list indexed by tuples, say, data[(row,col)], how do I remove an entire column?  I know in Matlab, I can do something like

```
 new_data = [data(:,1:x-1) data(:,x+1:end)];
```

if I wanted to remove column x from data.

(3) How can I easily count the number of non-negative elements in each row.  For example, in Matlab, I can do something like this:

```
 sum(data>=0,1)
```

this would give me a column vector that represents the number of non-negative entries in each row.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know if it will help with finding an equivalent Python operation, but removing a whole column from a matrix can also be done with the syntax `data(:,x) = [];` in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks everyone! NumPy/SciPy was exactly what I needed.  The syntax was pretty close to Matlab.  Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Isn't it great? If you're Matlab user, then you'll find ipython absolutely indispensable together with Numpy/Scipy. Object orientation, such as (data>=0).sum() or data.size or data.shape(), makes Numpy/Scipy even better than Matlab, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with everyone. Use Numpy/Scipy. But here are specific answers to your questions.

1. Yes. And the index can either be a built-in list or a Numpy array. Suppose `x = scipy.array([10, 11, 12, 13])` and `y = scipy.array([0, 2])`. Then `x[[0, 2]]` and `x[y]` both return the same thing.
2. `new_data = scipy.delete(data, x, axis=0)`
3. `(data>=0).sum(axis=1)`

Careful: Example 2 illustrates a common pitfall with Numpy/Scipy. As shown in Example 3, the `axis` property is usually set to 0 to operate along the first dimension of an array, 1 to operate along the second dimension, and so on. But some commands like `delete` actually reverse the order of dimensions as shown in Example 2. You know, row major vs. column major.

Answer (score 8):

You should look into [numpy](https://numpy.org/), it's made for just this sort of thing.

Comment: numpy will do everything asked in the question, with nearly exactly the same syntax as matlab.

Comment: Numpy arrays are the way to go. I recommend this page to help make the transition easier - http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users

Answer (score 3):

1. No, but dicts can.
2. Sounds like you want a "2d array", matrix type, or something else.  Have you looked at [numpy](https://numpy.org/) yet?
3. Depends on what you choose from #2, but Python does have [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and other functions that work directly on iterables. Look at gen-exprs (generator expressions) and list comprehensions. For example:

```
row_count_of_non_neg = sum(1 for n in row if n >= 0)
# or:
row_count_of_non_neg = sum(n >= 0 for n in row)
# "abusing" True == 1 and False == 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to easily create an array (matrix) in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

here is how it is displayed

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

and how to get a row or column:

```
>>> a[0,:]
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a[:,0]
array([1, 4, 7])
```

Hope the syntax is clear from the example! Numpy is rather powerfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand list functionality to allow indexing with tuples by overloading the __getitem__ and __setitem__ methods of the built-in list. Try the following code:

```
class my_list(list):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple) and len(key) > 0:
            temp = []
            for k in key: temp.append(list.__getitem__(self, k))
            return temp
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self, key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, data):
        if isinstance(key, tuple) and len(key) > 0:
            for k in key: list.__setitem__(self, k, data)
        else:
            list.__setitem__(self, key, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   L = my_list([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
   T = (1,3)
   print(L[T])
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) 
I don't think you can use a tuple as an index of python list. You may use list of list ( e.g. a[i][j]) but it seems that it's not your point. You may use a dictionary whose key is tuple.

```
d = { (1,1):1, (2,1):2  ... }
```

(2) 
If you don't mind about the performance,

```
map( lambda x: d.remove(x) if x[1] = col_number, d.keys() )
```

(3)
You can also use the filter to do that.

```
sum(
map( lambda x:x[1], filter(lambda x,y: x[1] == row_num and y > 0, d.items()))
)
```

Comment: Combining map or filter with lambdas is awkward, compare to a generator expression: `sum(y for x, y in d.items() if x[1] == row_num and y > 0)` (which should be equivalent to your code, but your code appears to have a bug).

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't the case that a list can be indexed by anything but an integer. A dictionary, however, is another case. A dictionary is a hash table consisting a key-value pairs. Keys must be unique and immutable. The value can be objects of any type, including integers, tuples, lists, or other dictionaries. For your example, tuples can serve as keys, since they are immutable. Lists, on the other hand, aren't and, thus, can't be dictionary keys.

Some of the capabilities you've asked about could be implemented as a combination of a dictionary and list comprehensions. Others would require subclassing the dictionary and adding methods to implement your desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Using native python you could use:

```
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
index_tuple = (1,2)
x = [item for idx, item in enumerate(my_list) if idx in index_tuple]
```